# make long table into a wide table

Tags: tables, formatting

I would like to rearrange my table so that it is "wider" rather than "longer." I'll show you what I mean.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

%TABLE:
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table1}
    \raggedright
%\centering
Firm Performance, 2010-2017

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{N} 
                                & \thead[l]{Mean} 
                                &
&  \thead[l]{Median}
&                                
                                \\
    \midrule
N   &  528        & 13150          \\
Mean salary (thousands)
            & 873.5 (14.244)   & 824.4 (3.7423)       \\
    \addlinespace
Standard deviation   & 327.3             & 429.1             \\
t Value & 2.60$^{*}$   & 3.33   $^{*}$    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like the table to resemble this:

[image]

Can you help? I got stuck as soon as I tried to add another column.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit:
Here is another example of me having issues adding columns. I cannot add a third column, even though I was able to add a second. Is this because there isn't enough room in the table? Please try my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}



\begin{document}


%TABLE:
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table}
    \raggedright
    %\centering
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
            \thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
             \thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{Stock Awards}
             \thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{Total Compensation}



                                                                \\
    \midrule
N   &    0.0     &         \\
Mean 

            &  0.0 &     \\
    \addlinespace
Median   & 0.0             &             \\
Min & 0.0   &    \\
Max & 0.0   &    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE (super close)

The table is still a bit tight. Ideas? Maybe reduce the font size?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table2}
    \raggedright
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017
    \medskip

    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lllll@{}}
    \toprule
   &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
   &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
   &  \thead[l]{Stock \\Awards}
   &  \thead[l]{Total \\Compensation}
   \\
    \midrule
    N        & 12,727     &  12,727  & 12,727  & 12,717  \\
    Mean     & 826.36     & 185.17   & 2,583.90  & 6441.41  \\
   \addlinespace
    Median   & 785.00     & 0.00   & 1,495.12   & 4,515.53  \\
    Min      & 0.00     &  -8.72  & -655.00  & 0.00  \\
    Max      & 8,100     & 27,549.88   & 131,939.70  & 156,077.91  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For every column that you want to add, you also have to add a column specifier like `r`, `l `, ... to `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}`. Additionally, you might have to reconsider the width of your table as a wider table most likely does not fit into one column.

Comment: Unrelated, but please check your preamble. You load some packages twice, like `booktabs` and `makecell`.

Comment: @leandriis , thanks for the response. Please see an updated question in the original post

Comment: I still find your question a bit unclear. To me it seems as if you wanted to have a total of 5 columns (part between `\toprule` and `\midrule`) but you still just use three column specifiers. Nevertheless, your table will most likely not fit into one (text) column. You therefore might consider using a table that spans over both (text) columns using `table*`. Alternatively you could also introduce line breaks in column headers, but without seeing some actual content of the table, it is quite hard to tell which is the best alternative.

Comment: where do I add table* ?  Also, "you also have to add a column specifier like r, l , ... to \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}" i'm having trouble understanding what this would look like

Comment: You can replace both occurences of `{table}` by `{table*}` and remove the `[H]`. Please keep in mind that this will influence the position of the table, because floats spanning two columns will typically be placed on top of a page.

Comment: For five columns that are all left aligned (and a table that spans one text column), you would use something like `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l l l l l}`. In your example, `@{}` is used to remove some padding on the left and right of the table, while `L` is a flexible width column. You could therefor use `{@{}L l l l l @{}}` in your example.

Comment: @leandriis thanks. That's just what I was looking for. Although you are correct--it doesnt fit on this half of the page. Could you show me how to extend the table across the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE shows three different possibilities on how to insert your table into a two column document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table}
    \raggedright
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Lllll@{}}
    \toprule
   &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
   &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
   &  \thead[l]{Stock Awards}
   &  \thead[l]{Total Compensation}
   \\
    \midrule
    N        & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Mean     & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
   \addlinespace
    Median   & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Min      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Max      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
    \end{table*}

\lipsum

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table2}
    \raggedright
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017
    \medskip

    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lllll@{}}
    \toprule
   &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
   &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
   &  \thead[l]{Stock \\Awards}
   &  \thead[l]{Total \\Compensation}
   \\
    \midrule
    N        & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Mean     & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
   \addlinespace
    Median   & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Min      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Max      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\end{table}





\begin{table*}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table3}
    \raggedright
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017
    \medskip

    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
   &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
   &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
   &  \thead[l]{Stock Awards}
   &  \thead[l]{Total Compensation}
   \\
    \midrule
    N        & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Mean     & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
   \addlinespace
    Median   & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Min      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    Max      & 0.0     &    &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\end{table*}
 \lipsum

\end{document}
```

- The first variant uses `table*` as suggested in the comments and additionally sets the tabular to span the complete width of the page (`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}`. This does look quite strange as the first column that only contains single words is stretched quite much.
- The second variant uses linebreaks in the column heading by inserting a `\\` inside the `\thead` command. I have also reduced the `\tabcolsep` by one pt to make the table fit into the column width.
- The last example shows a table that spans both columns but dos not use a flexible width column from `tabularx`. The table is therefore narrower than the textwidth. I have therefore centered the table on the page, but this looks quite strange due to the very short and left aligned caption.

To draw a conclusion: I would use variant 2 as long as the contents of the table are not too wide. But as already said in the comments, it is quite hard to evaluate which alternative is the best without seeing these contents.

Comment: it looks AMAZING. Wow. Thanks so much for working your magic! It's just tight in a couple places. If you have a solution then great--if not maybe I can just take away some decimal places in the numbers. Let me know! the update will be in the original post.

Comment: Leandriis, I posed the above question in the main page, in case you dont get a chance to get around to it.

Comment: @texmex, its look like that you liked answer and that it solve your problem. why you not vote it and even accept?